# How to use column selection in Having Clause but not in Group By Clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep bumping into this problem and I know there must be a simple solution but I can't find it.

I am wanting to get a count of the serials per part between certain dates. So without the date selection it looks like this.

```
SELECT 
    Part_Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No) AS 'Serial Frequency'
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Part_Name
```

And I get a count of serials per part.

```
part1    55    
part2    32   
part3    48 
etc etc
```

So now I want this to be selected between two dates. I know I need to use Having but this forces me to add it to the group by section, and then it no longer gives me the count totals but each part individually. I.E.

```
SELECT 
    Part_Name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No) AS 'Serial Frequency'
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Part_Name, Grade_Date
HAVING Grade_Date > '2016-06-01' AND Grade_Date < '2016-07-01'
```

Output:

```
part1 1  
part1 1  
part1 1   
part2 1  
part2 1 
etc etc
```

What obvious thing am I missing here because surly this can be done? If I don't include it I get this error

> Column 'Inventory.Grade_Date' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `where` clause because you are comparing actual values not the aggregated ones.

```
SELECT 
Part_Name,
Grade_Date,
COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No) AS 'Serial Frequency'
FROM Inventory
WHERE Grade_Date > '2016-06-01' AND Grade_Date < '2016-07-01'
GROUP BY Part_Name,Grade_Date
```

Comment: Oh my really! I swear I tried using where and it threw an error at me so I then associated having with group by. So having is when you are comparing something IN the group clause. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter by `Grade_Date` *before* doing the aggregation and you should not include `Grade_Date` in either the `GROUP BY` or `SELECT`:

```
SELECT Part_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Serial_No) AS SerialFrequency
FROM Inventory
WHERE Grade_Date > '2016-06-01' AND Grade_Date < '2016-07-01'
GROUP BY Part_Name;
```

Comments:

- I would expect the first comparison to be `>=`.
- Don't use column aliases that require escape characters.
- Don't use single quotes to define column aliases; only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- If the `DISTINCT` is not needed, then remove it.  `DISTINCT` incurs extra overhead for the calculation.

Comment: This is what I have been doing but it seemed like there must be a better way?

Comment: @Danrex . . . Your question does not suggest that this is what you have been doing.